# Keep cursor position element working with svg on top?

Tags: javascript, svg, cursor

My cursor position script works but not when the cursor is over the svg logo in the middle. Anyone know how to fix this??

Here is the site:

http://in-form2016.calarts.edu/

Answer (score 0):

SVG wasnt placed within the gradient class